# JSON:API authorization

Tags: authentication-authorization

I'm at the early stages of trying to figure out the Drupal JSON API and can't figure out what's causing the following errors.

> Some resources have been omitted because of insufficient authorization.

> The current user is not allowed to GET the selected resource in the response.

Is there a header I should use? It's all local so there's no basic auth to get past.

The code I am using is the following one.

```javascript
  fetch('http://localhost/domain-6/jsonapi/group_content/microsite-group_menu-main', {
    method: 'GET',
    mode: 'no-cors',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/vnd.api+json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.api+json'
    }
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error('Error: ', error);
  });
```

The response I get is the following one.

```json
{"jsonapi":{"version":"1.0","meta":{"links":{"self":{"href":"http:\/\/jsonapi.org\/format\/1.0\/"}}}},"data":[],"meta":{"omitted":{"detail":"Some resources have been omitted because of insufficient authorization.","links":{"help":{"href":"https:\/\/www.drupal.org\/docs\/8\/modules\/json-api\/filtering#filters-access-control"},"item--XQp4cup":{"href":"http:\/\/localhost\/domain-6\/jsonapi\/group_content\/microsite-group_menu-main\/470ce30a-b29a-440c-9dfd-62ec2ecc2174","meta":{"rel":"item","detail":"The current user is not allowed to GET the selected resource."}},"item--1lQ8DZL":{"href":"http:\/\/localhost\/domain-6\/jsonapi\/group_content\/microsite-group_menu-main\/fd53a4be-b3b3-4fba-8739-fe10bf3594b5","meta":{"rel":"item","detail":"The current user is not allowed to GET the selected resource."}},"item--CMmFdif":{"href":"http:\/\/localhost\/domain-6\/jsonapi\/group_content\/microsite-group_menu-main\/44e9ad5d-f644-49d4-9b06-8393fe9f179b","meta":{"rel":"item","detail":"The current user is not allowed to GET the selected resource."}},"item--35OuqGr":{"href":"http:\/\/localhost\/domain-6\/jsonapi\/group_content\/microsite-group_menu-main\/993f1dd0-7479-42f2-8cdb-4ad37f69b08d","meta":{"rel":"item","detail":"The current user is not allowed to GET the selected resource."}},"item--S9wgeIz":{"href":"http:\/\/localhost\/domain-6\/jsonapi\/group_content\/microsite-group_menu-main\/5d327513-431a-47fc-ad60-7d118cb75e28","meta":{"rel":"item","detail":"The current user is not allowed to GET the selected resource."}},"item--GadCb5C":{"href":"http:\/\/localhost\/domain-6\/jsonapi\/group_content\/microsite-group_menu-main\/73420f3a-f77b-40bc-b72c-0529c7c4a7e0","meta":{"rel":"item","detail":"The current user is not allowed to GET the selected resource."}},"item--whX9lWC":{"href":"http:\/\/localhost\/domain-6\/jsonapi\/group_content\/microsite-group_menu-main\/186316e4-42a5-4551-b3e3-f2d8d0c924b3","meta":{"rel":"item","detail":"The current user is not allowed to GET the selected resource."}},"item--0ZPeOPd":{"href":"http:\/\/localhost\/domain-6\/jsonapi\/group_content\/microsite-group_menu-main\/2b309be4-721d-4000-ab31-811b4c04b15e","meta":{"rel":"item","detail":"The current user is not allowed to GET the selected resource."}},"item--rMyrlTp":{"href":"http:\/\/localhost\/domain-6\/jsonapi\/group_content\/microsite-group_menu-main\/bdfc8224-04a9-4795-add5-f363c2433229","meta":{"rel":"item","detail":"The current user is not allowed to GET the selected resource."}},"item--59LnH0e":{"href":"http:\/\/localhost\/domain-6\/jsonapi\/group_content\/microsite-group_menu-main\/c5dcd0f8-b594-4567-b15f-a0a64b5186b7","meta":{"rel":"item","detail":"The current user is not allowed to GET the selected resource."}},"item--3WKSiq1":{"href":"http:\/\/localhost\/domain-6\/jsonapi\/group_content\/microsite-group_menu-main\/9e76a2a3-e121-4650-b83e-f9425c17a4bf","meta":{"rel":"item","detail":"The current user is not allowed to GET the selected resource."}},"item--jjQ9TP2":{"href":"http:\/\/localhost\/domain-6\/jsonapi\/group_content\/microsite-group_menu-main\/ae2b6217-be02-49de-9e01-b6c4a9b67e72","meta":{"rel":"item","detail":"The current user is not allowed to GET the selected resource."}},"item--dhiafhE":{"href":"http:\/\/localhost\/domain-6\/jsonapi\/group_content\/microsite-group_menu-main\/61119a05-877c-44c8-940b-fab317c0dc5d","meta":{"rel":"item","detail":"The current user is not allowed to GET the selected resource."}},"item--c7850PO":{"href":"http:\/\/localhost\/domain-6\/jsonapi\/group_content\/microsite-group_menu-main\/d636ea7f-f453-47e5-9536-c2b8f3f50c92","meta":{"rel":"item","detail":"The current user is not allowed to GET the selected resource."}},"item--ngkUSZk":{"href":"http:\/\/localhost\/domain-6\/jsonapi\/group_content\/microsite-group_menu-main\/a0f48948-e846-4d23-9bbf-4d4b7ccc3507","meta":{"rel":"item","detail":"The current user is not allowed to GET the selected resource."}},"item--2oP7rlR":{"href":"http:\/\/localhost\/domain-6\/jsonapi\/group_content\/microsite-group_menu-main\/a6625804-294c-493b-a904-fb1f561573c6","meta":{"rel":"item","detail":"The current user is not allowed to GET the selected resource."}},"item--Sz5wBPb":{"href":"http:\/\/localhost\/domain-6\/jsonapi\/group_content\/microsite-group_menu-main\/267f6042-ad6e-411e-8925-006877a7c9ad","meta":{"rel":"item","detail":"The current user is not allowed to GET the selected resource."}},"item--tMDa2oF":{"href":"http:\/\/localhost\/domain-6\/jsonapi\/group_content\/microsite-group_menu-main\/ccf1fd6a-921e-4144-97bf-e7d85b4dbdf8","meta":{"rel":"item","detail":"The current user is not allowed to GET the selected resource."}},"item--vYs3zKx":{"href":"http:\/\/localhost\/domain-6\/jsonapi\/group_content\/microsite-group_menu-main\/7187c2ba-6ee7-435c-9166-3fc0ce8fb421","meta":{"rel":"item","detail":"The current user is not allowed to GET the selected resource."}},"item--5vJmCru":{"href":"http:\/\/localhost\/domain-6\/jsonapi\/group_content\/microsite-group_menu-main\/10ba20cc-f0b6-4365-9b34-221452e4a0fc","meta":{"rel":"item","detail":"The current user is not allowed to GET the selected resource."}},"item--23KRMeA":{"href":"http:\/\/localhost\/domain-6\/jsonapi\/group_content\/microsite-group_menu-main\/5096f25f-4359-4cb7-9ec0-335b088d24bd","meta":{"rel":"item","detail":"The current user is not allowed to GET the selected resource."}},"item--exhD7mi":{"href":"http:\/\/localhost\/domain-6\/jsonapi\/group_content\/microsite-group_menu-main\/be7d1151-8f65-4eef-8fdc-a936a6cde937","meta":{"rel":"item","detail":"The current user is not allowed to GET the selected resource."}},"item--UISA0FF":{"href":"http:\/\/localhost\/domain-6\/jsonapi\/group_content\/microsite-group_menu-main\/89fdb64c-6e33-4237-8137-fad965fb7614","meta":{"rel":"item","detail":"The current user is not allowed to GET the selected resource."}},"item--Fzg9qbP":{"href":"http:\/\/localhost\/domain-6\/jsonapi\/group_content\/microsite-group_menu-main\/b69894a9-e7b0-4d63-aecb-069ae054c09f","meta":{"rel":"item","detail":"The current user is not allowed to GET the selected resource."}},"item--qPBbJA1":{"href":"http:\/\/localhost\/domain-6\/jsonapi\/group_content\/microsite-group_menu-main\/ae6d8f9b-0725-4fee-9c5d-cd25c8bbe583","meta":{"rel":"item","detail":"The current user is not allowed to GET the selected resource."}},"item--EqTCJ1N":{"href":"http:\/\/localhost\/domain-6\/jsonapi\/group_content\/microsite-group_menu-main\/f6c7d183-ff1a-497c-9dac-51d7bd927150","meta":{"rel":"item","detail":"The current user is not allowed to GET the selected resource."}},"item--uF6v1TR":{"href":"http:\/\/localhost\/domain-6\/jsonapi\/group_content\/microsite-group_menu-main\/b2db9f2e-1907-4fdf-aa49-1370d0bcf54d","meta":{"rel":"item","detail":"The current user is not allowed to GET the selected resource."}},"item--MV28pBq":{"href":"http:\/\/localhost\/domain-6\/jsonapi\/group_content\/microsite-group_menu-main\/8313b799-5f10-4416-ba20-49c2de2834a9","meta":{"rel":"item","detail":"The current user is not allowed to GET the selected resource."}},"item--wVd7rsP":{"href":"http:\/\/localhost\/domain-6\/jsonapi\/group_content\/microsite-group_menu-main\/346bdf69-93ec-4127-a483-e7d687b20e2d","meta":{"rel":"item","detail":"The current user is not allowed to GET the selected resource."}},"item--h0VjXuJ":{"href":"http:\/\/localhost\/domain-6\/jsonapi\/group_content\/microsite-group_menu-main\/052730d5-18f5-47fb-834f-8ed6898031e1","meta":{"rel":"item","detail":"The current user is not allowed to GET the selected resource."}},"item--fcA5aED":{"href":"http:\/\/localhost\/domain-6\/jsonapi\/group_content\/microsite-group_menu-main\/fcdebbce-047b-4cfa-a185-67ae7e01262c","meta":{"rel":"item","detail":"The current user is not allowed to GET the selected resource."}},"item--3dDdcIg":{"href":"http:\/\/localhost\/domain-6\/jsonapi\/group_content\/microsite-group_menu-main\/450b3119-4d70-41ee-aecf-6ffe77e76f71","meta":{"rel":"item","detail":"The current user is not allowed to GET the selected resource."}},"item--3XlVwNC":{"href":"http:\/\/localhost\/domain-6\/jsonapi\/group_content\/microsite-group_menu-main\/917f9200-6a48-40e2-9c56-e3834fe392f3","meta":{"rel":"item","detail":"The current user is not allowed to GET the selected resource."}},"item--QtN7OYa":{"href":"http:\/\/localhost\/domain-6\/jsonapi\/group_content\/microsite-group_menu-main\/de886c77-ebd0-41de-a4ee-872113f6afec","meta":{"rel":"item","detail":"The current user is not allowed to GET the selected resource."}},"item--Q6uGw9H":{"href":"http:\/\/localhost\/domain-6\/jsonapi\/group_content\/microsite-group_menu-main\/9ede015d-28b5-4e61-a3ad-1a65b0527f34","meta":{"rel":"item","detail":"The current user is not allowed to GET the selected resource."}},"item--qwxls5H":{"href":"http:\/\/localhost\/domain-6\/jsonapi\/group_content\/microsite-group_menu-main\/f12a3922-26c2-47b1-8e62-ff7efb9b005a","meta":{"rel":"item","detail":"The current user is not allowed to GET the selected resource."}},"item--ngPbsJJ":{"href":"http:\/\/localhost\/domain-6\/jsonapi\/group_content\/microsite-group_menu-main\/e4540be8-f206-46de-94a6-57a5f7b20ab3","meta":{"rel":"item","detail":"The current user is not allowed to GET the selected resource."}},"item--AnR0WT0":{"href":"http:\/\/localhost\/domain-6\/jsonapi\/group_content\/microsite-group_menu-main\/2d0a7020-11d4-4536-a446-fc8450a31559","meta":{"rel":"item","detail":"The current user is not allowed to GET the selected resource."}},"item--AhzT8c6":{"href":"http:\/\/localhost\/domain-6\/jsonapi\/group_content\/microsite-group_menu-main\/402e1e71-ec7c-46c4-bc5b-a3b925df70b4","meta":{"rel":"item","detail":"The current user is not allowed to GET the selected resource."}},"item--Wm2v9pb":{"href":"http:\/\/localhost\/domain-6\/jsonapi\/group_content\/microsite-group_menu-main\/4f475314-c892-43ab-bb0f-5e1d265cc4d0","meta":{"rel":"item","detail":"The current user is not allowed to GET the selected resource."}},"item--kd0J901":{"href":"http:\/\/localhost\/domain-6\/jsonapi\/group_content\/microsite-group_menu-main\/78909988-22e9-491d-a47e-229c0a7a225e","meta":{"rel":"item","detail":"The current user is not allowed to GET the selected resource."}},"item--404rztx":{"href":"http:\/\/localhost\/domain-6\/jsonapi\/group_content\/microsite-group_menu-main\/a13ff285-dfda-4949-b85d-67af424fdc92","meta":{"rel":"item","detail":"The current user is not allowed to GET the selected resource."}},"item--G4zUasD":{"href":"http:\/\/localhost\/domain-6\/jsonapi\/group_content\/microsite-group_menu-main\/afc8da9b-b945-4013-b4e6-7cfda013b57c","meta":{"rel":"item","detail":"The current user is not allowed to GET the selected resource."}},"item--hC13Nrz":{"href":"http:\/\/localhost\/domain-6\/jsonapi\/group_content\/microsite-group_menu-main\/61c25a67-06ed-4831-8f25-e4849632a91e","meta":{"rel":"item","detail":"The current user is not allowed to GET the selected resource."}},"item--PWp8vHM":{"href":"http:\/\/localhost\/domain-6\/jsonapi\/group_content\/microsite-group_menu-main\/7c3fa94e-4d4c-4a74-b5ee-8909d2481054","meta":{"rel":"item","detail":"The current user is not allowed to GET the selected resource."}},"item--Nzyn35g":{"href":"http:\/\/localhost\/domain-6\/jsonapi\/group_content\/microsite-group_menu-main\/cd43deee-5f44-4f23-9708-58163cd8150d","meta":{"rel":"item","detail":"The current user is not allowed to GET the selected resource."}},"item--IZapjnH":{"href":"http:\/\/localhost\/domain-6\/jsonapi\/group_content\/microsite-group_menu-main\/5fc7df8b-1429-4c05-b0d0-6042f53992ad","meta":{"rel":"item","detail":"The current user is not allowed to GET the selected resource."}},"item--Tf1PVbP":{"href":"http:\/\/localhost\/domain-6\/jsonapi\/group_content\/microsite-group_menu-main\/ae718931-248f-4d8f-9923-626445d66056","meta":{"rel":"item","detail":"The current user is not allowed to GET the selected resource."}},"item--WIAJdC5":{"href":"http:\/\/localhost\/domain-6\/jsonapi\/group_content\/microsite-group_menu-main\/804424f6-bf31-4689-a935-dd92082325e2","meta":{"rel":"item","detail":"The current user is not allowed to GET the selected resource."}},"item--g2Rs5um":{"href":"http:\/\/localhost\/domain-6\/jsonapi\/group_content\/microsite-group_menu-main\/24d7998f-eca9-4c7e-9ddc-f544e0cab691","meta":{"rel":"item","detail":"The current user is not allowed to GET the selected resource."}}}}},"links":{"next":{"href":"http:\/\/localhost\/domain-6\/jsonapi\/group_content\/microsite-group_menu-main?page%5Boffset%5D=50\u0026page%5Blimit%5D=50"},"self":{"href":"http:\/\/localhost\/domain-6\/jsonapi\/group_content\/microsite-group_menu-main"}}}
```

Comment: The answer below is probably correct, but it's unclear what "it's all local" means. Does that mean the browser is fetching from the same origin? Cross-origin?

Comment: The Drupal site and the site that consume the API are both on localhost.

Answer (score 1):

probably no access due to the fact that:

"fetch won’t send cookies"

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: I added `credentials: include` to the fetch options object but that didn't work.